# Creating an Activity with the same background than ICS settings / Preferences

Tags: android, background, themes

I am working on an app for ICS and I would like my Activity to have the same background than the settings, with the cool gradient.

I tried Theme.DeviceDefault and some other, but I cannot get it.

Is that possible or should I forget?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed 2 things:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    (...)/>
```

Works fine now..

Comment: You may want to use `Theme.Holo` instead, since that is the actual theme and DeviceDefault can change by device.

Comment: Thatś working fine on my GNEX. If a manufacturer wants to use an other background, I want to use the manufacturer background!

Answer (score 13):

It is relatively simple to create this app background directly yourself.

drawable/app_background_ics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:startColor="@color/ics_background_start"
    android:endColor="@color/ics_background_end"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="ics_background_start">#ff020202</color>
   <color name="ics_background_end">#ff272D33</color>
</resources>
```

Then add the app_background_ics drawable as a background to your main view (in this example ListView).
Do not forget a transparent android:cacheColorHint in order to avoid a black background when scrolling in the ListView

```
  <ListView android:id="@+id/video_list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:dividerHeight="2dip"
  android:background="@drawable/app_background_ics"
  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
```

Comment: upvote for being at the age of knowing how to get things done (Cialis commercial reference)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Theme.Holo.Dark`?

Comment: There are no such theme.. :-p

Comment: Sorry, it is called `Theme.Holo` (reference: "Honeycomb holographic theme (dark version)"), which exists since API level 11. Since I use `Theme.Holo.Light`, I thought that the dark one is called ".Dark" :D